# Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 Scope Create Remove Issues

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

This is my first application using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 so you assume i don't know any thing of it.

The question is i need to synchronize tables- these number of tables to synchronize increase or decrease as the Database changes. 
Like wise the direction of tables is also random in nature sometimes it is up or down or bi-directional. Even the rules vary

As we have large no of clients/distributors so the no of tables to synchronize for UserA may be different for UserB and even the direction.

As we need to create Scopes and what i find out we need to create a new Scope for every change and for every User Tables is it right?

**So Example we have 100 tables 10 Users and 3 directions then the possibility of no of scopes will be above 3000**

How to the number of scope effect the **DB performance?**

Even i dont know how can i remove scopes for the tables that are deleted in DB? or that i choose not to synchronize and even for the user also.

I found out there is something called as Deprovisioning but dont know how to use it.

Moreover  i need to apply filters to the tables also so in that case do i need to create a new Scope again or not? I don't know how to create filters as the samples i downloaded does not have any example of filters?

Any **help/sample/link** is highly appreciated

Comment: I dont know if users does not understand the question how can they downvote and say this is not a real question without asking for any explanation

Comment: Moons: It's the responsibility of question-askers to make their questions well-defined and clear; this question seems to be neither.

Comment: @Nightfirecat Yes you may be correct but i have specified all the issues of Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 scopes etc and any person who has ever worked on it is able to answer the question thats what i think. May be this time all the persons find this question vague

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a scope is a collection of tables that are sync together in a single sync session. how many tables to include is up to you.

have a look at this link for some guidance: [Sync Framework Scope and SQL Azure Data Sync Dataset Considerations](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/sync-framework-scope-and-sql-azure-data-sync-dataset-considerations/)

I suggest you go thru the documentation and the tutorials/walkthroughs first. The documentation actually gets installed with the framework.

if you have trouble finding them, here's the corresponding links:

[How to: Use Synchronization Scopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg294195.aspx)

[How to: Provision and Deprovision Synchronization Scopes and Templates (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928603.aspx)

[How to: Filter Data for Database Synchronization (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928701.aspx)

if you want to understand further what provisioning actually does, have a look at this: [Sync Framework Provisioning](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/sync-framework-provisioning/)

you might want to specify what databases are you actually synching